# ¿Cómo puedo validar datos monetarios en R?

Tags: r, regex, validación

tenía un conjunto de datos en R de este estilo:

| Donante | Monto |
| --- | --- |
| A | 200.100,5 |
| B | 200,100.5 |
| C | 200100,5 |
| D | 200100.5 |
| E | 200100 |

Y quiero hacer una validación que me permita posteriormente dejar los valores de la siguiente forma:

| Donante | Monto |
| --- | --- |
| A | 200100,5 |
| B | 200100,5 |
| C | 200100,5 |
| D | 200100,5 |
| E | 200100 |

Agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Muestra qué has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask].

Comment: Bienvenido Lucas  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Entiendo que básicmente necesitas elimina los separadores de miles (coma), prueba con `gsub(',', '', df$Monto)`

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa que sirve para limpiar los datos que tienes como ejemplo. Si hay otras formas en la que están "mal" los datos quizás tengas que adaptarlo.

Son tres pasos:

1. Contar cuantas veces aparece símbolo `,` o `.`, porque en algunos casos aparece dos veces y hay que eliminar la primera aparición.
2. Usar eso como condicional para eliminar el primer `,|\\.` que aparezca. Al `.` hay que escaparlo pq es caracter reservado en regex. Uso `str_remove()` que, a diferencia de `str_remove_all()` remueve solo la primera aparición de una cadena.
3. Cambiar `,` por `.` y pasar a numérico.

```
library(tidyverse)

#Creo unos datos similares a los tuyos

read.table(text = 
"Donante Monto
A   200.100,5
B   200,100.5
C   200100,5
D   200100.5
E   200100", header = TRUE) -> foo


foo %>% 
  mutate(Monto = if_else(str_count(Monto, ",|\\.") > 1, 
                      str_remove(Monto, ",|\\."), 
                      Monto)) %>%
  mutate(Monto = as.numeric(str_replace(Monto, ",", ".")))

  Donante    Monto
1       A 200100.5
2       B 200100.5
3       C 200100.5
4       D 200100.5
5       E 200100.0
```

Para un caso más complicado en el que pudiera haber más de dos separadores arbitrarios (puntos o comas) se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
foo %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  mutate(separadores = str_count(Monto, ",|\\.")) %>%  #Cuento cuantos separadores hay
  mutate(separado = str_split(Monto, ",|\\.")) %>%     #separo en una lista

# Paso por la lista y me quedo con todos los elementos menos el último, que debería ser el decimal
  mutate(enteros = unlist(map2(separado, separadores, ~.x[1:.y]) %>% 
           map(~paste(.x, collapse = "")))) %>%   #Los pego
#Ahora capturo los decimales
  mutate(decimal = unlist(map2(separado, separadores, ~.x[.y+1]))) %>% 
#Atiendo el caso especial de los números son decimal (poco elegante, es lo que hay)   
  mutate(decimal = ifelse(separadores == 0, 0, decimal)) %>% 
#Hago el pegote final, uso el . como separador que es válido en R
  mutate(Monto_final = paste0(enteros, ".", decimal))
```

Está muy enredado, pero funciona. La idea es usar `str_split()` para separar las partes y usar la referencia sobre el número de separadores para después rearmar el Monto, usando el último elemento de la lista como decimal.

Comment: Hola, una consulta tenia una respuesta parecida a la tuya en la cual llegamos al mismo resultado, pero mi pregunta es, en el caso que tuvieras mas de 2 ( . ) o ( , ), el str_remove solo removerá la primera aparicieron, quedandote de nuevo con el mismo problema, es decir, existe alguna expresion regular que elimine todas las aparicienos excepto la ultima?

Comment: No sé con regex, que no soy bueno usándolas. Quizás sí. Con R se pueden aprovechar las estructuras de datos y los números de índice para separar al Monto en partes y después volverlo a unir. Actualicé la respuesta con una solución (no muy elegante) al caso de un número arbitrario de separadores.